# How do I change the location where screenshots are saved in Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, defaults, screenshot

Pressing <kbd>PrnScr</kbd> "Print Screen" on the keyboard results in a screenshot being silently saved under /home/%user%/Pictures/

How can I change this location?

Comment: I know this question specifies Mint, but since it shows up in Google for Ubuntu. FYI anyone on 18.04+, Ubuntu doesn't use Gnome-screenshots, it uses a settings daemon. The dconf auto-save directory is ignored (it's a WONT_FIX bug). The only way to set the save location is with a Gnome Tweaks extension: https://askubuntu.com/a/1102530/783117

Answer (score 11):

Open `dconf-editor` (note that you may need to install it first: `sudo apt install dconf-editor`)

Navigate to `org.gnome.gnome-screenshot`:

> - org
>
>   - gnome
>
>     - gnome-screenshot

Then enter a value for **auto-save-directory** in the format **file:///path/to/directory/**
e.g

```
file:///home/yourusername/Pictures/screenshots/
```

Comment: Note: Be sure to press enter when you have finished typing the value entry so that it is saved. If the dconf Editor window looses the focus your changes will be discarded unless you have pressed enter to "Enter" them. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Using the **terminal**

Setting the **auto-save-directory**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory '/home/yourpath'
```

Getting it

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory
```

Comment: Note that despite its name, the "auto-save-directory" only provides a default directory for saving. It does NOT save automatically without popping up a dialog.

Comment: Works on Cinnamon 19.3